# Django - JavaScript translation problem

Tags: django

Hi I have a problem with JS translation in Django.
I did everything like is said in documentation, so:
I made .po then .mo files (django.mo, djangojs.mo).
Translated files are in path: *myapp/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/* and *myapp/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/*
**Translations in .html and .py files work OK.** The only problem is that JS translation always displays original phrase, not translated.
main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog',{}), )
```

template file in header (as first JS part):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
```

All my js files are in path /myapp/site_media/js/ and the only .mo files are in path which I wrote before.
I use gettext() in JS strings.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what do you see when direct you browser at http://your.site/jsi18n/ ?

Comment: have the same problem, my jsi18n is http://dpaste.com/755946/ - as you can see, only django strings are translated

Comment: can you provide an example of a file with an indicated js translation? JS translatables must be in a .js file, if not you should use the `{% trans %}` tag.

Answer (score 2):

To use the jsi18n view you have 2 options:

1. Specify the desired translation packages in the dict passed to the view, which will be combined (you've specified an empty dict - hence no packages)
2. Catch the packages parameter in the url pattern, and specify the package names in the url, separated with +.

This is described in the [javascript_catalog documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog). Maybe you've missed it. I suggest taking another look: